# Importing existing java dynamic web project into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I import a **java web project** into **Eclipse IDE**. in the import dialog there is only a **war** file upload can be selected. But I couldn't find something like import a project.

[image]

So how can I import an existing java web project. Thank You!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can always import your project that you have made it, previously with Eclipse using the "Existing Project into Workspace" option.

It will directly load all the packages of your Dynamic web Project, related to Eclipse Folder Structure.

And if you want to import a Web Project which is may be made with using other IDE than Eclipse and if it is pure web project than use WAR import, because it is a complete way to import any web project. For this prerequisite is that when Exporting the project you have it in WAR file.

**Note:-** I have not worked with other IDE than Eclipse that much. So I can say that there may be others who knows how to import project created from other IDE than Eclipse.

Comment: most .gitignore files I've found prevent .project .settings which makes a pain the project to be added to eclipse easily. What would you recommend when there is no .project .settings file?

Comment: @nacho4d as far as I know for eclipse folder structure you'll need .project file.

Answer (score 6):

Use New -> Java Project -> A window will open -> Uncheck Use Default Location -> Browse to the root of the project -> Finish

Answer (score 3):

You can import existing projects(any type) from below location in Eclipse

```
File > Import > Existing Project into Workspace
```

Answer (score 2):

Using that 'existing projects into workspace' you have already highlighted? Assuming you're talking about an existing Eclipse project, and not about a project which has only code. Otherwise you just create a new web project and you copy the source to it.

Comment: I thought it's for java-SE projects. OK. Thanks.